# How to get Windows user name when identity impersonate="true" in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, impersonation

I'm creating an intranet asp.net mvc application that everyone in the company should have access to.  I need to run the website impersonated for database access etc., but I want to know who each user is.

When I look at `Page.User.Identity.Name` it's blank.  Is it possible to get the user's windows account name even though the site is running impersonated?

**Edit:**
Here's a little more info.  I have a site in IIS 6 running with anonymous access enabled.  The site is running under a system account that has access to the database (because all of the employees do not have access to the database).

My web.config has `<authentication mode="Windows" />` and `<identity impersonate="true"/>`

My goal is that the users won't have to log in - that fact that they are logged into our network (and the fact that the site is not on an external IP) is enough authentication.  I would just like to know who the user is in order to track changes they make, etc.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

With `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` in your application and Anonymous access enabled in IIS, you will see the following results:

```
System.Environment.UserName: Computer Name
Page.User.Identity.Name: Blank
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name: Computer Name
```

With `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` in your application, and ‘Anonymous access’ disabled and only ‘Integrated Windows Authentication’ in IIS, you will see the following results:

```
System.Environment.UserName: ASPNET (user account used to run ASP.NET service)
Page.User.Identity.Name: Domain\ Windows Account Name 
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name: Computer Name\ASPNET
```

With `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` and `<identity impersonate ="true"/>` in your application, and ‘Anonymous access’ disabled and only ‘Integrated Windows Authentication’ in IIS, you will see the following results:

```
System.Environment.UserName: Windows Account Name 
Page.User.Identity.Name: Domain\ Windows Account Name 
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name: Domain\ Windows Account Name
```

Comment: This is one of those answer where I wish there was a favorite answer, like the favorite questions

Comment: @BlackTigerX There is, you can award bounties to outstanding answers... Doing so gets you the Altruist badge *First bounty you manually award on another person's question*

Comment: Why doesn't Microsoft include clear, short explanations like this in their documentation? Thank you for this answer.

Comment: What about Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name? If you add this as well, I think it will be more complete.

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

It should return a string with the users login name

Comment: Thanks Gav - I tried this and it displays the name of the account that my site is setup to run under (see the Edit in the question for more info).

Comment: Think your going to need to disable annonymous access in IIS, when they visit the site assuming they are logged into the domain IIS will use their current login. The code above should then display their UserID rather than the one IIS runs under.

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to post my fix, because no one else had said anything about it.

I was having the same issue when I published the site to the server, but not on my local.  All the settings were the same.  However, in IIS the "Default Website" had never been turned off. It was running and intercepting traffic, even though there was no site associated with it.  Anonymous Authentication was turned on in the default, but turned off in my website running under port 80.  It didn't seem to matter that my site had it turned off... since the default was turned on it was turned on for all traffic to port 80.

Disabling the default web fixed the issue.  Also changing the port to 8080 works.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Unless this functionality has changed under the MVC framework, and I don't think it has, Page.User.Identity.Name should still work.  Sounds like your site is set up to allow anonymous authentication.  If so, try disabling it.

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  I added some more detail to the question, but basically I need anonymous authentication.

Comment: Given the additional information, you want `<identity impersonate="false"/ >`.  You want the web app to run under the identity provided by IIS.  `impersonate="false"` makes sure this is the case.  You also want to turn Integrated Authentication on and disable anonymous authentication.  This insures that Page.User.Identity will be the identity of the user viewing the page.  They shouldn't have to actually provide credentials if the server and users are on the same domain.

Comment: And sorry for taking so long to reply.  I haven't had a chance to participate here in a while.