# Get the local system's user name

Tags: asp.net, localsystem

In my web application, I need to display the username who is currently logged in the system. Am having a Text-box and a Button in my form. Example : If the user **"Admin"** is currently logged in and using the **(Local)system**. Once I clicked the button the name Admin has to be displayed in the Text-box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Windows user name when identity impersonate="true" in asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267071/how-to-get-windows-user-name-when-identity-impersonate-true-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code for getting current username

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please refer this code for Asp.Net

```
string currentUsername = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

This is tested code.