# ASP how to get authorization rules in code? Not section from web.config, but actual rules

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, windows-authentication

Well, to be honest, problem is why 'currentUser.Identity.Name' is blank.
Options are:

```
`<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>
<identity impersonate ="false"/>`
```

And IIS 7 Integrated Windows Authentication is enabled, 'Anonymous access’ disabled.
(It was mantioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267071/how-to-get-windows-user-name-when-identity-impersonate-true-in-asp-net))
App is executing on local computer, in the same domain.
When I'm trying to write:

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="MY_USER_NAME"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I get page 401.2, access forbidden.

And now, i think, options are inhereted from somwhere, and 'Anonymous access’ is still enabled. So, how i need to check the actual value in code.

**UPDATE**
Role manager is this:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Problem solved, I changed IIS options, but programm was executed with IIS Express...

Comment: please do not just edit "Solved" give an answer yourself and mark it as correct