# Get Windows Logon From Within ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, windows-identity

Just like the title states. Need the windows logon and domain info from within our asp.net page.

I tried

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

but it returns the IIS App Pool not the user name

Thanks

Comment: HTH http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267071/how-to-get-windows-user-name-when-identity-impersonate-true-in-asp-net

Comment: Perhaps this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Where do I set "<identity impersonate ="true"/>" in my web.comfig?
Also, I did a test and the IsAuthenticated is False.

Answer (score 4):

Try [`HttpContext.User`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), accessible simply as `User` from the code behind. It returns both the domain and username, but should be easy enough to trim for your needs. It's worked for me in the past. You can also use this to manage roles in your application, if you need to.

**EDIT**
Below are the relevant portions of my web.config. I also used [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to setup the tables needed for the role manager in my database. I could then use `User.Identity.Name` and `User.Identity.IsInRole`

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlRoleManagerConnection"
         connectionString="myConnectionString">
    </add>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleManager">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlRoleManager"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
             connectionStringName="SqlRoleManagerConnection"
             applicationName="myAppName" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: In order for this to work, you need to either set up the app in IIS or in web.config to not allow anonymous users, or you're going to get a blank.

Comment: @Tim See edit, added relevant portions of web.config

Answer (score 0):

This is my code in VB.net

var strUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

so C# must be in the lines of: (not tested)
string strUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

In the Web.Config file

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <identity impersonate="true" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```