# How to connect to a database with trusted connection in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application that uses Windows Authentication and the SqlRoleManager provider.  I am trying to connect to a database with integrated security.  The database team is requiring that each user be authorized to use the database using Windows authentication rather than a simple user name and password that can be used for the web application.    I used the code below and found out that the principal is actually the app pool user.  How do I attach the session to the current windows user?  Is that even possible?

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
Response.Write(identity.Name);
```

Comment: Is changing the user under whom the app pool runs not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to try:

- Turn on impersonation in the .config via **identity** .config node
- Perform impersonation in the code around db access via WindowsImpersonationContext (never tried this - slow?)
- Go through Context.User.Identity.Name (not sure if this fully gets you what you need).

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267071/how-to-get-windows-user-name-when-identity-impersonate-true-in-asp-net).

Excerpt from [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28v=vs.98%29.aspx):

> The Context.User.Identity.Name property returns the authenticated
>   user's identity. When the application runs in IIS 7, and impersonation
>   is disabled, the Environment.UserName property returns the identity of
>   the application pool that the Web application is running in. For
>   example, if the Web site is running in the default application pool,
>   the name DefaultAppPool is displayed. If the ASP.NET v4.0 application
>   pool is used, ASP.NET v4.0 is displayed.

Comment: I just set the impersonation = true in the web.config and now I am getting a different error:  The NTLM authentication token is not supported

Comment: That link from Adam has some good guidance on the NTLM token issue.

Answer (score 1):

We have a post on msdn regarding this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z(v=vs.100).aspx