# Web API, APIController, Empty User

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a standard web form app which is authenticated using IIS's *Windows Authentication* setting.

As I now need to expose some the data via Web API, I have added an APIController which I can successfully retrieve the required data, however, I need to restrict what is returned based on the identity of the requestor.

The problem is that the `this.User.Identity` is coming back empty..

```
[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]: {System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity}
AuthenticationType: ""
IsAuthenticated: false
Name: ""
```

I am new to Web API so not sure what I have done wrong / forgotten to do...

FYI - The authentication on the web form app is working perfectly...

Comment: @granadaCoder Sorry... I can't remember what happened with this, it was over a year ago now... I think I took a different approach to WebAPI

Comment: Ok..thanks for checking in.

Answer (score 2):

Having "anonymous authentication" enabled..along side of "windows authentication" will create this "empty windowsIdentity" problem.

Longer discussion (and my problem and answer) here:

[HttpClient calling a Windows-Authenication ApiController Method...but no WindowsIdentity coming along for the ride](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887865/httpclient-calling-a-windows-authenication-apicontroller-method-but-no-windows)

Also see:

[How to get Windows user name when identity impersonate="true" in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267071/how-to-get-windows-user-name-when-identity-impersonate-true-in-asp-net)