# asp.net webapi Windows authentication get username on an impersonated call

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, impersonation

For some reason I can't get the windows username on an impersonated call.
I have followed the answers
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267071/how-to-get-windows-user-name-when-identity-impersonate-true-in-asp-net) but not getting the same result.

On server A I have a intranett ASP.MVC application with only windows authentication in IIS.
[image: IIS server A]

In the web config for the mvc application on server A, I use impersonation.

[image: Web.config, server A]

Code for calling web api

```
var impersonationContext = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate();
using (impersonationContext)
{
   var client = GetHttpClient();
   return await client.PostAsync("services/ExecuteCommand/Execute", httpContent);
}
private HttpClient GetHttpClient()
{
   var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
   {
      UseDefaultCredentials = _commandServiceUseDefaultCredentials
   };
   var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
   {
      BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CommandServiceBaseUrl"].ToString()),
   };
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));       
   return client;
}
```

On server B i have a ASP.Net Web API (Core) project with windows authentication

[image: IIS server B]

In the web config for the web api on server B a specify using windows authentication, but NOT impersonation.

[image: Web.config, server B]

I'm trying to get the windows username for the person browsing my mvc application. I have tried a lot so I ended up with this method to get them all.

```
private string GetUserName()
{
   var windowsIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
   System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity2 = null;
   if (System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current != null)
      if (System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext != null)
         windowsIdentity2 = System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity;

   var httpContextIdentity = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
   return string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}",
                System.Environment.UserName ?? "",
                User.Identity.Name,
                windowsIdentity != null ? windowsIdentity.Name : string.Empty,
                windowsIdentity2 != null ? windowsIdentity2.Name : string.Empty,
                httpContextIdentity != null ? httpContextIdentity.Name : string.Empty);
}
```

This yields this result

> System.Environment.UserName:  ServerB App_pool user without domain
>
> User.Identity.Name:  Domain\ServerA$
>
> System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name: ServerB
>   domain\app_pool user
>
> System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name:
>   (null)
>
> System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity: Domain\ServerA$

So how can I get the windows username for the end user of my mvc app?

Comment: I guess your application is running in Integrated mode.In that case, try adding following in your web.config <system.webServer>
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>

Comment: It is there already :-(

Comment: Have windows authentication ON and Impersonation Disabled. Following is the output. Logged in User : HttpContext.User.Identity.Name || App Pool Domain Account : WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name (Domain\UserName) || App Pool Domain Account : Environment.UserName (Just User Name) –