# ASP.NET Impersonation in IIS

Tags: asp.net

ASP.NET Impersonation
I have a site hosted on IIS that has anonymous authentication and forms authentication both enabled.

Initially I have `impersonation Turned Off`.  So before logging in using forms authentication for,

> System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

I get a value of `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`

when i enable impersonation I get a value `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`

After logging in with forms authentication regardless of whether I have impersonation turned or or off.. I am always getting a value of `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`

My question is.... if I have impersonation turned on and I log in using JSMITH's account, shouldn't I be getting a value of `JSMITH`

Comment: Isn't the whole point of impersonation to... well, *impersonate* (a different user account)?  Why are you expecting it to assume the *original* login?

Comment: so if i have impersonation turned off.. then i should see JSMITH?

Comment: If memory serves, Forms Authentication doesn't require a Windows account.  It follows that IIS would log in with its own authority.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication?view=netframework-4.8, in the **Remarks** section.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267071/how-to-get-windows-user-name-when-identity-impersonate-true-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

Impersonation doesn't run as the user you've logged in as, it just allows you to run your application under a specified user account.

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\username" password="P@$$word"/>
```

This will run as `domain\username`.

If you want to use the user account that's logged in you will want to look at something like *Forms Authentication* or *Windows Authentication*.

Comment: apparently when I use forms authentication it doesn't matter whether i have impersonation on or off.. its always running under IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool